# Regular Expression for specific count of letters and digits in a word.

Tags: regex, perl

In a file I have to fetch a string which contains exactly 5 letters followed by 5 numbers.
Some examples: `TSDMN12345 TSDRD34526 PSSTN84586`

Please help me how to match these.

Comment: Please supply some more context, and ideally some sample inputs and outputs. It is generally considered bad form to just present your needs without explaining where you are at with your own attempts (easiest is to just show some code). That is because your *real* problem is not going to be "I know nothing, please write my code" but perhaps you don't know how to specify an exact character count in a regex. We cannot tell that if you just ask for a direct solution, and the question is not so useful

Comment: http://regexr.com/ could be useful for you. You probably want something like /[a-zA-Z]{5}[0-9]{5}/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
   if($str=~/^[a-zA-Z]{5}\d{5}$/){
       ...
    }
```

Explanation:

`^` - Beginning of a string

`[a-zA-Z]{5}` - exacly 5 english characters of upper or lower case

`\d{5}` - exacly 5 digits between 0 to 9

`$` - end of a string

Comment: [a-zA-Z] will match a very limited subset of letters out there in the real world -- which might not be an issue for this user's question, but might trip up a future searcher.

Answer (score 1):

You need character classes (for "any letter" and "any number"), and then you need to specify how many occurrences to match.

```
/^
  [[:alpha:]]{5} # 5 letters
  \d{5}          # 5 digits
$/x
```

(Note that the x on the end just allows us to use arbitrary whitespace to make our regex more legible)

Alternatively, based on your sample data you only care about upper case ASCII letters, in which case you can go for the much simpler

```
/^[A-Z]{5}\d{5}$/
```

The Perl documentation contains [perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html) and [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) which I'd highly recommend.

Answer (score -1):

You can match the string against:

`"^[a-zA-Z]{5}\d{5}$"`